# How to find my IDLE's Python, then apply pip upgrade to a package it uses?

Tags: macos, pip, python-2.x, python-idle, skyfield

I have two python 2.7's of interest:

- version with IDLE that came from https://www.python.org/downloads/
- anaconda 2.7 installation

I use MacOS. (I understand I'm overdue to switch to Python 3)

I'd like to apply `pip install --upgrade PackageName` to a package that IDLE's Python uses, but when I type that in my terminal it tries to apply it to my anaconda version.

Is there a way I can find my IDLE's python, point to it, then apply the `pip` command to it?

Here's what I have:

```
$ which python

/Users/david/anaconda2/bin/python

$ which -a python

/Users/david/anaconda2/bin/python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

---

**update:**  Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54811749/3904031) I've opened IDLE and typed

```
import sys
sys.executable
```

and it returned `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python`.

I then opened a terminal and entered `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -m pip install --upgrade skyfield`

and I received the following:

```
Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/skyfield/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) - skipping
Requirement already up-to-date: skyfield in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/jplephem/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) - skipping
Requirement already up-to-date: jplephem>=2.3 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from skyfield)
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/sgp4/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) - skipping
Requirement already up-to-date: sgp4>=1.4 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from skyfield)
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) - skipping
Requirement already up-to-date: numpy in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from skyfield)
```

I close IDLE then reopen it, then type

```
import skyfield
skyfield.__version__
```

and still it's only `1.0`

No update.

Skyfield is currently on version `1.10` https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/installation.html and I upgraded my anaconda version successfully today to `1.10` using `pip install --upgrade skyfield`

Comment: I am guessing that anaconda does not directly use pypi as the repository for user upgrades.  Open another SO question or post to python-list about the certificate issue.  It has nothing to do with IDLE.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy I'll think about posting a new question; I think I understand what you are saying, but I'm not confident I understand well enough to write a question and answer all comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To find your IDLE's version, open `IDLE`, the go to the `help` section in the menubar. Hit `About IDLE`, and there is your python version!

To verify that your pip is the version you want, all you have to do is type this:

```
pip -V
```

It will give you something like this on Windows (MAC will be similar):

```
pip 19.0.2 from c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip (python 2.7)
```

In the case that is the incorrect path, just get `get-pip.py` then run it using the python version you want it to compile to like this:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```

To use the pip you wish to use, type this:

```
/usr/local/bin/pip install foo
```

Comment: Just hit `escape` then type `:q`

Comment: "In the case that is the incorrect path..." how would I know if that path is the correct path or the incorrect path?

Comment: You would compare the pip to the IDLE path you desire.

Comment: If your your desired IDLE path is 2.7 then your good to go (pip is fine)!

Comment: The first line of `/usr/local/bin/pip` is `#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python` and I have just executed `pip install --upgrade PackageName` and my package was upgraded for my anaconda distribution, and not for the IDLE version. I don't think installing another `pip` should be necessary here. I have asked "How to find my IDLE's Python..." and that still seems to be undefined.

Comment: No, I have typed that and the error includes `Requirement already up-to-date:` I believe we have not yet found the correct python. I think "How to find my IDLE's Python..." needs a more definitive answer.

Comment: You've just re-asked my question! "How to find my IDLE's Python..."

Comment: I updated the answer to a more efficient a reliable method to find IDLE's path, and get the version of python pip ins running on.

Comment: Here is my about IDLE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDQNK.png here is my help: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0D5H.png

Comment: That means your IDLE version is 2.7.11

Answer (score 1):

In the IDLE shell, enter `import sys; sys.executable` and you will see full path to the python that is executing IDLE.

To install to that specific executable, enter in Terminal `path/to/python.exe -m pip install ...`.

Comment: I've done so, I will post the results back into the question, I don't understand the message but I don't see a change.